# This paper implies that $a \frac{\partial{b^\ast}}{\partial{q}} = b \frac{\partial{a^\ast}}{\partial{q}}$ and I don't see why.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This question is regarding a particular paper that claims a particular result that I cannot seem to follow. The paper is: [Cyclic Spectroscopy of the millisecond pulsar, B1937+21](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/779/2/99/meta) (The paper should be Open Access and I am mainly referring to equations 18-20).

While I attempt to provide an explanation of the problem below that does not require reading the paper, I am providing the paper as a source in case I have genuinely missed something else that was the key to figuring this out.

---

The paper defines a complex function (of multiple complex variables),

$$R \equiv S - D$$

where $S$ is a complex function of multiple complex variables (representing some model) and $D$ is a complex function of the same variables as $S$ (representing some observed data). Another real function is then defined,

$$ M \equiv  \sum R^\ast R $$

which represents sum-of-squares that must be minimized (to optimize for $S$ ultimately).

Now, taking the derivative of $M$ with respect to some model parameter $q$ (which can be complex), the paper claims the following is true,

$$ \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{q}} = 2 \sum{R \frac{\partial{S^\ast}}{\partial{q}}} $$

I do not see how this follows.

---

Working through it myself, I go through the following steps:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{q}} &= \sum{\frac{\partial{R^\ast R}}{\partial{q}}} \\
&= \sum{ R\frac{\partial{R^\ast}}{\partial{q}} + R^\ast\frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{q}} } \\
&= \sum{ R\frac{\partial{S^\ast}}{\partial{q}} + R^\ast\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{q}} }
\end{align}

The final step follows from the fact that $\partial{D}/\partial{q} = 0$ since $q$ is a model parameter and $D$ is representing data and is therefore, constant in this context.

However, I do not get the result the paper authors achieve. Their result would seem to imply that,

$$ R\frac{\partial{S^\ast}}{\partial{q}} = R^\ast\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{q}} $$

which is not something that is obvious to me.

**What am I missing or what assumptions are necessary for the above equation to be true?**

Comment: We have $R\partial S^* = (R^* \partial S)^*$ and $M$ is real so $2\,\text{Re} \sum [R\partial S^*]$ would be correct in any case. If it holds anyway then you would need $R\partial S^*$ or equivalently $S\partial S^*$ to be real and this doesn't hold in general. If $S = re^{i\theta}$ then $S\partial S^* = |S|^2(\partial r/r - i\partial\theta )$ which is only real if $\partial\theta = 0$ so the phase has to be constant with $q$ (or just zero derivative at the point of interest).

Comment: I think your point about recognizing that $M$ being real implies the other side of the equation must be real is very helpful and something obvious that I missed. But I am having trouble following the rest of your comment. Would you be willing to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: I haven't read the paper so it was just a general observation (and what I noted is basically just the fact that if $z = z^*$ then we must have $z$ being real). There might be some conditions on $S$ or something with the sum that does this, but figuring this out requires a proper reading of the paper.